# Using the Riemann Extension Theorem to prove connectedness of $U \setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> **Riemann Extension Theorem**: Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain, $g \in \mathcal{O}(U)$ such that $g$ is not identically zero. Let $N = g^{-1}(\{0\})$ be the zero set of $g$. If $f \in \mathcal{O}(U \setminus N)$ is locally bounded in $U$, then there exists a unique $F \in \mathcal{O}(U)$ such that $F\vert_{U \setminus N} = f$.

I'm trying to use the above theorem to prove the following problem

> Suppose $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is open, connected and $f \in \mathcal{O}(U)$. Show that the complement of the zero set, $U \setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is connected.

but I have no way of attacking this with the theorem. Usually it is easier to show path-connectedness rather than directly showing connectedness, but considering two distinct points $a,b$ in $U \setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$ does not give me a direct way to argue that there should exist a path between these two points.

Thinking about this in $\mathbb{C}$ the only way that $U \setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$ would become disconnected is if $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ splits $U$ into two pieces and I'm guessing if this happens, then it violates the extension theorem, but how?